# Freeze a frame using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm processing a video using ffmpeg filter `-vf` command. I'd like to freeze a frame at a specific time offset (basically I'd like to replace all video frames starting from 00:20:00 by the frame at 00:19:59). Is it possible to do by adding another filter to my command?

I know how to achieve this with running multiple ffmpeg commands, but I'm seeking a simple solution using filters to simplify my pipeline to only one ffmpeg command :) I saw some suggestions that overlay/tpad filters might be used for this but so far I'm struggling to find a good command.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show your solution with multiple ffmpeg commands?

Comment: The solution with multiple commands is (2) im ny gist: https://gist.github.com/vadimkantorov/1ac694cd849a70d128f93759e93e6374

There I extract some frame, then create a video using this frame and the audio and then concat the two together.

Also, I don't know if mp4 supports audio streams longer than the video streams (then I could just trim the video at 00:19:59 and keep the audio somehow running). If this is possible, maybe it's possible to somehow mux such a video...

Answer (score 1):

Assume we know the duration of the input from advance, we may chain `trim` filter with `tpad` filter.

For example, assume the input duration is 50 seconds, and we like to keep the first 20 seconds, and repeat the last frame for the remaining 30 seconds:

`ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -vf "trim=duration=20,tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=30" out.mp4`

The `trim=duration=20` trims the input video to 20 seconds, and  `tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=30` clones the last frame (of the first 20 second) for 30 more seconds.

For automating the process, we may use FFprobe for getting the duration, and prepare the FFmpeg command using a shell script (or a Python script).

---

Assume we don't know the duration of the input, and we don't want any kind of programming, we may use the `overlay` filter for keeping the duration of the input:

`ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=duration=20,tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=1000000[v1];[0:v][v1]overlay=shortest=1" -c:a copy out.mp4`

- `[0:v]trim=duration=20,tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=1000000[v1]` - trims the input to 20 seconds and clone the last frame for extremely long time.
  The result is stored in the temporary name `[v1]`.
- `[0:v][v1]overlay=shortest=1` - Overlays `[v1]` over the input video.
  The total duration is determined by the duration of the input video due to the usage of `shortest=1`.
  Note that `overlay` filter is only used for keeping the duration (`[v1]` hides `[0:v]` when overlayed over it).
- `-c:a copy` - copies the audio stream without re-encoding.

---

For testing, we may use synthetic video file (generated using FFmpeg):

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=192x108:r=1:d=50 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -shortest -c:a copy in.mp4`

Then executing:
`ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=duration=20,tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=1000000[v1];[0:v][v1]overlay=shortest=1" -c:a copy out.mp4`.

The 20'th frame is repeated for the last 30 seconds.
The audio is kept unmodified.